# Biztalk in alwayson SQL 2019

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, msdtc

Good morning all

I am working on a Biztalk migration project On an alwayson SQL environment

Who has an idea if BIztalk is compatible with ALWAYSON if YES it is from Which version?

another question for the activation of the MSDTSC function should you activate this option in Always on

thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/high-availability-using-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups) yet?

Answer (score 1):

Biztalk is compatible with `ALWAYS ON` from `SQL Sever 2016`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/high-availability-using-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups

You have here a brief [introduction](https://www.sqlshack.com/explore-cross-database-msdtc-for-distributed-transactions-in-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups/) and a [setup](https://www.sqlshack.com/deploy-msdtc-for-distributed-transactions-in-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups/) of Microsoft Distributed Transaction (`MS DTS`). Microsoft says that is available starting from [SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-availability-group-for-distributed-transactions?view=sql-server-ver15).

I found a [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/msdtc-best-practices-with-an-availability-group/ba-p/909429) that is talking about best practice and is mentioning `Biztalk` which is exaclty your scenario but.... it doesn't give any example about how to setup `MS DTS` with Bitztalk.